# Convert image into Uint8Array in Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, http, opencv, request

I am getting this error trying to convert an image into a `CvMat`:

> Error: Imencode - expected arg 0 to be a Buffer of Uint8 Values

This seems easy enough to fix, although I don't know how to convert an image into a `Uint8Array`, which is what the function is asking for. Here's my code so far:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    let uint8Array = new Uint8Array(body);
    let imageCvMat = cv.imdecode(uintArray)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original goal was to be able to pass an image from a URL into `cv.imdecode()`. Turns out the way to do this is with a `Buffer`, and this works like a charm:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    let buffer = Buffer.from(body);
    let imageCvMat = cv.imdecode(buffer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are opencv4nodejs for implementing your solution. I would like to direct your attention to a few aspects.

You can check it out here that imdecode & imencode accept buffers as input
[opencv4nodejs imdecode](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/opencv4nodejs/docs/cv#imdecode)

So basically the issue that I have faced as well is that you are not converting your image into Mat using imdecode in first place. Kindly check the input you are providing & try fixing it.

Comment: Yeah that’s my question - how do I convert it to the necessary input?